# How to load clienttemplates.js in publishing page

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, client-side-rendering

I would like to insert some CSR (client side rending) code on every page of a site collection. Hence I added the related line in the Master page. Later I found all the publishing pages do not trigger the code. `clienttemplates.js` is not loaded by default. May I know is there any reason `clienttemplates.js` is not loaded? Can I simply add `<SharePoint:ScriptLink>` to include the `clienttemplates.js`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure `clienttemplates.js` is loaded before setting up your client side rendering.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", CSR_Setup);

function CSR_Setup() {
    // Client side rendering code
}
```

Comment: I added <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="clienttemplates.js" OnDemand="false" runat="server" Localizable="false" /> to Master page it force load clienttemplates.js. However I think SPClientTemplates is not called so my script fail to RegisterTemplateOverrides anything. Publishing page cannot use CSR?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add that. As far as I know, there is no limitation with CSR in publishing pages. Did you try what I suggested in your JavaScript?

Comment: By using F12 tool, I confirmed clienttemplates.js is not loading unless I added the ScriptLink tag. But I am not sure whether it means CSR is applying. In my script there is function [onPostRender(renderCtx)] but this function never fire in publishing pages.

Comment: I believe SP.SOD.executeFunc is ensure clienttemplates.js is loaded. If clienttemplates.js is not loaded, the SP.SOD.executeFunc will not be triggered?

Comment: `SP.SOD.executeFunc` ensures that `clienttemplates.js` is loaded before the `CSR_Setup` function is called (in my example). So you DO NOT need to use a `ScriptLink`.

Comment: You probably DO need to use a ScriptLink because even though the function is not called until clienttemplates.js is loaded, the external script might be loaded after the views on the page have already rendered and therefore the loading of the script is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add into your MasterPage, in the end of the HEAD section, this block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("clienttemplates.js", "/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js");</script>
```

This will register  SOD name `clienttemplates.js` on your page.  Then, in the BODY, try code  suggested by Submits:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", CSR_Setup);

function CSR_Setup() {
    // Client side rendering code
}
</script>
```

Also notice, in some cases, all content on page is loading async, so may by your CSR-code is executing before content is fully loaded? If this is your case, you can call your functions after `sp.bodyloaded` event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified(CSR_Setup, "sp.bodyloaded");
</script>
```